# acer laptop windows 8: how to repair/replace the hardware which holds the foil?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Is there anything i can do apart from replacing the motherboard completely?

I've broke the component which holds the keyboardfoil in attempt to remove that keyboard. Also a small amount of water got in probably.

Comment: What model laptop?

Comment: There's a generic track repair guide here - http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/10836-how-to-fix-a-broken-membrane-keyboard-logitech-g15-gen1/

Comment: I'm not sure i checked the sheets it says: Marketing Name: Aspire E1 series; Aspire E1-571; Aspire E1-571G; Aspire E1-521. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If internal traces on a multilayer board are damaged, it would be difficult to fix (one would need to know what trace was broken inside the board and bridge it with a wire), but for a surface trace and connector, you could try automobile *rear-window defroster repair liquid*, which dries to a conductive silver.

Since traces are *very* narrow, use a single hair or a pin to paint; bridging (short-circuiting) traces can be damaging. This would be a fragile fix, and might benefit from being covered with tape or epoxy as reinforcement. *There's no guarantee the repair will work*, especially if there's water damage. [*Pure* water will likely dry without harm but *salt* water is very corrosive, particularly if there was a battery or the power supply was on].

See http://www.frostfighter.com/defroster-repair-fix-it-guide.htm, [http://www.amazon.com/Permatex-09117-Complete-Window-Defogger/dp/B000ALBZJY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ALBZJY) and http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/permatex-complete-rear-window-defogger-repair-kit-09117/7160063-P.

Please let me know if this works.